How to pass stored procedure parameters as dynamic content in copy activity using ADF
I have design copy activity pipeline in ADF and called a stored procedure and which take two parameters as input.
I want to use the parameters as dynamic content in copy activity when stored procedure call.
You can see the pipeline and stored procedure and two parameters:

The issue that I am facing is that I am unable to use these two parameters as dynamic content and unable to write the json expression.
In this screenshot, there is option available to pass the values as dynamic:

Is there any way to pass these two values as dynamic content in copy activity to a stored procedure call? Thank you for your consideration and time.

You can pass the parameters as dynamic content in the parameters value option. After creating the parameters, in the parameter value, click on Add dynamic content and you can add the dynamic expressions here.

Here, for sample I am passing the string and integer variables from ADF pipeline to the stored procedure parameters.

Execute the pipeline and you can check whether the values of these expressions passing correct to the parameters or not in the input section of the copy activity run details.

UPDATE:
As your input parameter names are values are coming as a JSON from an activity, you can directly use the below dynamic expression.
@json(replace(string(pipeline().parameters.json),'''',''))

As I don't have any activity returning the JSON, I have stored the JSON object in a pipeline parameter json of object type and used it in the above dynamic expression. Instead of parameter, you can use your activity output which gives the required JSON object. Here, this expression converts the JSON object into a string and replaces the single quotes(') inside the string value with an empty space. After that, it converts the result string to JSON again which is the required JSON for passing parameters.

Copy activity input:


Thank you for being so considerate, but I want to pass JSON so you can see that there is an option to add dynamic content in the second picture. Is there any way to add it?

Do you want to pass a JSON to one of the parameter or do you have the JSON of parameter name and value to pass both parameters at once? If yes, Can you provide that JSON?

Thank you for being so considerate, but I want to pass JSON so you can see that there is an option to add dynamic content in the second picture. Is there any way to add it? URL of screenshot https://i.sstatic.net/f5ODLLg6.png

I want to pass both values once because there is a stored procedure that takes 2 parameters. and both values I am getting from previous activity. but not able to pass them into json as dynamic content

That dynamic content is for adding all stored procedure parameters in a JSON and passing at once. Do you need it that way? or do you want to pass the JSON as a parameter to the stored procedure?

Can you edit the question and add the JSON? and stored procedure script with the required values as parameters for better understanding? You can add a sample vaues with same structure.

I have a stored procedure [dbo].[Sp_GetTB_FeedData] that takes two parameters. The values for these parameters are stored in a database column sp_parameters. This column contains JSON like:
{
    "Calendars": { "type": "String", "value": "'FY24,FY25,FY26'" },
    "PPiviotLevel": { "type": "Int16", "value": "0" }
}

I need to fetch these parameter values from the database and pass them to the stored procedure during its execution. How can I achieve this effectively?

Understood your requirement. Give me some time. I will update the answer accordingly.

Thank you for your support if you do not mind also share the best way to save the values in the database because I think this approach is not good to save two values under one column json {     "Calendars": { "type": "String", "value": "'FY24,FY25,FY26'" },     "PPiviotLevel": { "type": "Int16", "value": "0" } }

Check the Update section of my answer to pass the above JSON as parameters. Coming to your comment, as your primary ask is related to passing parameters to the stored procedure, I think it's better to raise a new ask about your recent query with all relevant details like blockers and expected output so that I can try from my end.
